# Apple reject iPad app for having more then 7 tab bar items

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

So to have less then 7 tab bar items, the only solution is to have customized "More.." button?

Is there any other solution?

Comment: This is the recommended solution if you wish your app to be publicly available on the iTunes appstore. It's very common practice.

Comment: I'd suggest to reconsider the organization / navigation of your application. I find it hard to think of a reason why an app would have to have so many tab bar items...

Answer (score 2):

That's clearly stated in the human interface guideline.

Off course you can create your own navigation bar and even include horizontal scrolling into it so you can have as many 'tab' as you want.  I did this myself for a magazine app and that was accepted (tab were actually pages obviously)